# ABP Framework: Are there any websites in the real world that have been developed with the framework?

Tags: .net, frameworks, abp

Good evening

I have been developing SW for many years and now found the ABP framework.
Unfortunately, I found only academic mini-examples and not a single example of a useful website on the Internet developed with the ABP Framework.

**Is the ABP framework suitable for real projects on the Internet?** Are there examples with more than a handful of business objects showing only a small part of a website project?

**I am considering using the ABP framework for a project that manages lectures,** with quite a few business objects:

- Organizations
- Lecturers
- Events
- Lectures with lots of metadata including table of contents with time and chapter information
- Several users working on transcriptions in parallel
- translations
- invitations
- Newsletter subscriptions
- appointments
- ...

Is there a good chance that the solution will work stable and that the can be well maintained (if it is well structured from the beginning, of course)?

Thanks a lot for any hint, kind regards,
Thomas Schittli

Comment: Hi Tom,
There are many real-world projects that developed via ABP framework. Most of them can be internal projects in the companies. You can look at https://abp.io/ and there are huge of documentation, examples, books etc. You can feel free to use ABP easily. 
Hope the answer is clear for you.
Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

There are many applications that are developed by using ABP Framework.

For example, all of the *.abp.io websites are developed with ABP Framework. You can see the list of these *.abp.io websites:

- [abp.io](https://abp.io/)
- [commercial.abp.io](https://commercial.abp.io/)
- [blog.abp.io](https://blog.abp.io/) (By using the Blogging module of ABP)
- [support.abp.io](https://support.abp.io/)
- [community.abp.io](https://community.abp.io/)
- [docs.abp.io](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest) (By using the Docs module of ABP Framework)
- and other websites.

---

Besides *.abp.io websites:

- https://www.openeventhub.com/ (Real-time distributed system application)
- https://github.com/abpframework/eShopOnAbp (Microservice solution)
- https://easycrm.abp.io/ (CRM application)
- ...

---

You can also check the customers of ABP Framework (also ABP Commercial) and their websites.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

an example, covid19 dashboard by [who.int](https://covid19.who.int) APIs are implemented by ABP Commercial.