# abp framework - users facing UI/modules

Tags: abp

I'm curious about the suitability of the ABP framework for user-facing applications. In your web app tutorial, you demonstrate how to build a book store, which seems more geared towards developers or maintainers rather than end-users. I'm wondering if the prebuilt UI options are designed primarily for this purpose and how the framework handles user-facing sites. Would you load a different theme and data based on user roles? Can you provide some insight into the approach for creating end-user interfaces?

Additionally, I'm interested in using the Chat module with a React web app. Is this possible with the ABP framework? do the modules only work on angular and blazor which means i have to have the admin dashbord and the user ui in the same codebase?

Comment: "In your web app tutorial" — Stackoverflow is a Q&A website for programmers. Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). It does not run the ABP project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Additionally, I'm interested in using the Chat module with a React web app. Is this possible with the ABP framework? do the modules only work on angular and blazor which means i have to have the admin dashbord and the user ui in the same codebase?

ABP does not support React officially. However, you can use the Chat Module's APIs and only implement the UI part by getting the source code of the Chat Module and examining it for Angular UI. Also, there are some React templates developed by the ABP Community, you might wanna check them.

> I'm curious about the suitability of the ABP framework for user-facing applications. In your web app tutorial, you demonstrate how to build a book store, which seems more geared towards developers or maintainers rather than end-users. I'm wondering if the prebuilt UI options are designed primarily for this purpose and how the framework handles user-facing sites. Would you load a different theme and data based on user roles? Can you provide some insight into the approach for creating end-user interfaces?

ABP Commercial provides a public-web option, that is primarily used for user-facing applications. There are too many applications that are built top on ABP Framework and ABP Commercial, so I think you should not think of the framework as only providing admin panels and modules to you, the main goal is to provide you with a well-designed infrastructure and speed up your development time.

You can change the theme by your tenant, add a new custom theme, change the existing ones, change the theme according to the user roles (you need to take action on your own for doing this), and more...

---

If you want to see some applications that are created by using the ABP Framework or ABP Commercial and also customers of ABP Commercial, you can check the following links:

- https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/15301
- https://commercial.abp.io/pricing (*Trusted By* section: Microsoft, Siemens, PWC, Standard Chartered etc.)
- https://www.openeventhub.com/ (Real-time distributed Event application)
- all *.abp.io websites (https://stackoverflow.com/a/72788085/10477283)